# How do I disable the right click when pressing the right side of my trackpad?

Tags: touchpad, vaio

I'm trying to figure out how to disable the right hand side of my trackpad in Ubuntu. The default behavoir is for the right hand side to right click. However, I would like a single click anywhere on the pad to act as a single click, while having a two finger press behave as a right click.

I also have a sony vaio T-series SVT13122CXS and am running 12.10.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just wondering if there were any other suggestions?

Comment: Edit the title. I thought you were asking how to make touches to the right side of the trackpad do nothing instead of moving the mouse.

Answer (score 13):

This did it for me:
http://kernpanik.com/geekstuff/2015/01/12/disable-rightclick-synaptics.html

For me this disabled the right hand side click area without disabling two finger "right-click".

Essentially, run this:

```
synclient RightButtonAreaLeft=0
synclient RightButtonAreaTop=0
```

To persist, add a script that does this into "Startup Applications".

Comment: GREAT! One problem... do you know how I can install synclient? I'm currently using Ubuntu GNOME. Thanks!

Comment: WFM! Thanks! @bioguy, on Linux Mint 17.3, it's `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid`

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did: (13 is where my synaptics device was)--I set left, center, and right to left-click, but did not disable scrolling.

xinput set-button-map 13 1 1 1 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Hrmmm.... sooo close. Scrolling works, and tapping or clicking anywhere on the pad acts as a left click. However, touching the pad with two fingers no longer acts as a right click.

Comment: Yes, this method will actually remap both two-finger click and right-bottom-click. At least that happened for me. (I added another solution below)

Answer (score 0):

First run the command

```
xinput
```

You will get output that looks like

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Multi-Input Device                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
....
```

The touchpad is the device with ID 16. Check the correct ID for your case.

Then, run the command

```
 xinput set-button-map 16 1 2 3 0 0 6 7 8 9
```

where

```
 16 is in my case the ID for the touchpad
 1 is the left click
 2 is the middle click
 3 is the right click
 0 we disable the scroll up (otherwise it would be 4)
 0 we disable the scroll down (otherwise it would be 5)
 6 ... we leave the rest as they are so we do not disable something important
```

Now the right side of the touchpad is disabled and does not respond to scrolling.

Comment: Hrmmm... well that almost works. I still want to be able to scroll up and down. Just disable right clicking when I click the right side of the pad.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the same problem on my Thinkpad. I'm sure it'll work on other machines with Synaptics trackpads as well:

https://askubuntu.com/a/572813/366397