# Disable right click option on a X1 Carbon Gen 2 Synaptics touchpad

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

I would like to disable the right click functionality when I click on the right side of the synaptic's touch-pad. I've tried the synaptic tool but it didn't apply the setting.

Below is a question that someone had a similar issue but answers given over there didn't end up solving my issue.

- [How do I disable the right click when pressing the right side of my trackpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217835/how-do-i-disable-the-right-side-of-my-trackpad)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using synclient:

Type `synclient -l` to list  your configuration. At the end of the output, you will find something like

```
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3068
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 4326
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
```

These values have to be changed to 0 (zero) by typing these two commands:

```
synclient RightButtonAreaLeft=0
```

and

```
synclient RightButtonAreaTop=0
```

Clicking anywhere on your trackpad will now always trigger a left-click. To right-click, do a two-finger click on your trackpad.

To make these changes permanent, write the two commands to a shell script and add the script to your startup applications:

```
nano ~/.synaptics-custom-settings.sh
```

Paste this code to the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient RightButtonAreaLeft=0
synclient RightButtonAreaTop=0
```

Open the Startup Applications program in Unity and add ~/.synaptics-custom-settings.sh to the list of startup applications.